# Nuances between "отчего/почему/зачем/откуда/куда шум"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Care to explain what's the deal with these earrings, **why such a fuss?**

I wanted to express this idea in Russian. I wonder which interrogative adverb is best suited for this context and how they are nuanced. I'm assuming that "зачем" is somehow different from the rest and not sure if "куда" in the sense of "what for" can be used this way.

> Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, **отчего** шум?
>
> Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, **почему** шум?
>
> Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, **зачем** шум?
>
> Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, **откуда** шум?
>
> Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, **куда** шум?

Comment: **отчего** is a good choice, a wee bit dated, but still correct, also **отчего** + ***такой/столько*** (to account for **such** and to sound more ideomatic); another option is ***с какой стати такой,столько***

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка alternative rendering of "such" would be "отчего ВЕСЬ ЭТОТ шум?"

Comment: together with the previous question - https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16286/ - I would stick with "почему" : "что такого в этих серёжках, почему такая суета?" - in this phrase the main question body is about "the deal with the earrings" and the "fuss" sub-question is used to specialize, to explain the main question. Of all the potentially reportable circumstances regarding the earrings I query specifically those c-es that explain the fuss. However in the short, laconic, generic phrases you offer "отчего" is indeed the better option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe none of these  would do. I'd rather say

> Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, **из‐за чего** шум/крик/скандал/кипеш/сыр-бор/ажиотаж?

Из‐за чего means "what's the reason of" or "what caused all that fuss?

Отчего, почему is used for reason, зачем for purpose, откуда for the place where it comes from,origin. Куда makes no sense.

Comment: "куда столько шумА?" could make a sense in a simple talk. But on the very very borderline of possible.

Comment: granted сыр-бор, неразбериха, шухер - while definitely low style might be better suited for translation of fuss in the context

Comment: Can you still use "из‐за чего" even when the cause of such a fuss is expected to be something positive?

Comment: Sure. Positive or negative,  that does not matter.

Comment: even шум-гам would probably better fit than шум alone. The question is about some mess, some active but seemingly aimless and chaotic activity, not about sound itself. Шум alone means noise and is quite technical term, mostly meaning a real sound. While it can somewhat be used as "fuss/mess" i'd still prefer using a more "shapeless" and less precise word.

Answer (score 1):

- Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, отчего шум?
- Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, почему шум?

"... why the fuss?" "Почему" sounds a little better, but there is no difference in the meaning.

- Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, зачем шум?

"... why create the fuss?" Implying "we/they don't need to attract attention".

- Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, откуда шум?

"... who is making the fuss?"

- Не объяснишь, что это за серьги, куда шум?

Not a proper Russian phrase. Will be understood, but  can appear as colloquial in some circles only.